# jQuery function not working in the header file

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm adding this jquery function in my wordpress header, it was working initially but I had to take off the code, now when I'm adding this back it wouldn't work! I 'm scratching my head on this for a while and can't find the solution, can anyone please help me...

```
<script>
(function($) {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();
    });
    $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function() {
      location.href = this.href;
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Diego! it worked!! :)

Comment: how would I disable the hover effect on the small screen? I just want the toggle button.

Comment: on click handler just use slideToggle()

Comment: sorry I'm not very good at this, do you mean  $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(slideToggle()

Comment: `$('.navbar .dropdown').click(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideToggle();
    });`

Comment: Thanks Diego this worked perfectly fine but there's a small issue, when I click on the parent item it the toggle works but it quicky redirects me back to the parent item page. Is it because of the timining how do I stop this ?

Comment: It's perfect for the big screen only on the small screen,

Comment: Try to remove the calling of `.delay(250)`

Comment: thanks, I removed  .delay(250) but still after a few seconds it would just disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Typing mistake!

```
</script>
... your code ...
</script>
```

should be

```
<script>
... your code ...
</script>
```